# Error during creation of Kafka Source with SASL_SSL: No such File

Tags: linux, ssl, apache-kafka, siddhi

Siddhi raise me No such File Exception but the file is exactly there (I have copied the path from the console). I have also tried adding file:// but it hasn't work either.

```
    @source(type='kafka',
         topic.list='pruebasSiddhi',
         partition.no.list='0',
         threading.option='single.thread',
         group.id='id1',
         bootstrap.servers='broker1:9092,broker0:9092',
         optional.configuration="""
         security.protocol:SASL_SSL,
         sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512,
         sasl.jaas.config:org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username='siddhi_Producer' serviceName='11111' password='1234';,
         ssl.truststore.location:/home/deploy/kafka/ssl/kafka.web.truststore.jks,
         ssl.truststore.password:secret,
         ssl.keystore.location=/home/deploy/kafka/ssl/kafka.web.keystore.jks,
         ssl.key.password:secret""",
         @map(type='json'))
```

If anyone can help I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found with `ps -aux | grep carbon` that it runs with an argument -Dwso2.runtime.path=PATH and changed ssl.truststore.location to `PATH/SSL/kafka.web.trustore.jks`. Obviously copying jks files to PATH/ssl

That worked for me :)